# Error changing sequelize-cli configuration to dynamic configuration

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am running into a problem, trying change the sequelize-cli configuration to dynamic configuration, as described in the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#dynamic-configuration). I created the .sequelizerc-file in the root-directory of my project and configured the path to config.js.

After running `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` I get the following error:

> Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.14.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3]
>
> Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
>
> Using environment "development".
>
> ERROR: Server requests authentication using unknown plugin sha256_password. See TODO: add plugins doco here on how to configure or author authentication plugins.

It doesn't matter if I try it on my development environment (localhost) or on my production environment (clearDB with heroku) I still get the same Error message, not being able to connect to the server. Without the dynamic configuration (config in a *.json) everything worked fine.

This is the content of my .sequelizerc file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
      'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js'),
}
```

and this is simply the content of my config.js

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.DB_PROD_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PROD_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_PROD_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_PROD_HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
  }
};
```

It doesn't matter if I try it on my development environment (localhost) or on my production environment (clearDB with heroku) I still get the same Error message, not being able to connect to the server. Without the dynamic configuration (config in a *.json) everything worked fine.

Comment: thank you! Just approved your edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

okay, after trying for a long time, I figured out, that my environment variables were `undefined` when I ran `npx sequelize-cli`-commands.

So i simply added `require('dotenv').config();` to my .config.js now it works.